# Database snapshot update

Tags: sql-server

I m a new in SQL. I have one question where if we update, i mean add or delete data at source database, is that the data will be update in database snapshot also. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database snapshots will not be updated with changes made on source database after snapshot is created.

You can drop existing snapshot and create it again for refreshing in a means

For example, if you use the same name for all snapshots on a specific db, you can drop it first and recreate snapshot once more with latest changes on source database

```
Drop DATABASE KodyazDB_ss 
go
CREATE DATABASE KodyazDB_ss 
ON (
NAME = KodyazDB,
FILENAME ='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\KodyazDB.ss'
)
AS SNAPSHOT OF KodyazDB;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's what snapshots are for: a static copy of the database at a specific instant. If you update the base database, the updated data pages are moved from the base database's data files to the the snapshots data files, with a "copy on write" operation, so that the snapshot always contains the same version of the data as when it was created.